# pytest no django "lazy_django.py no Django settings"

Tags: python, django, pytest-django

my project list:

```
main_project
 - tests/
 - main_project
  - project1/
  - django_project/
   - tests/
   - django_app/
   - django_project/
    - manage.py
```

now, when I on `main_project` path, run `pytest ./projects/django_project`, it can pass `django_project` pytest.

But I want run one `pytest` to run wholl pytest including `project1` & `django_project` on `main_project` path, it passed all `project1` pytests, but auto skipped `django_project`'s pytest, when I run with  `pytest -rsx` it shows:

`SKIPPED [2] .../local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest-django/lazy_django.py:14: no Django settings`

Any suggestion? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This error means pytest-django can't find your django settings. I had this same error and fixed it by adding a `pytest.ini` file and pointing to my django settings module:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = my_app.settings
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I exported some vars and  I solved it:

```bash
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings
export PYTHONPATH=/home/my_home/PycharmProjects/my_project/app
```

Of course the path will be different for you